# Видео HTML5 по центру

Tags: html, css, html5

Есть ли аналог background-sive: cover для видео? У меня на сайте показывается только верхушка видео, а нужно чтобы отображалась центральная часть.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вот вам готовое решение с видео.

```css
.top-video {
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 padding-bottom: 40%;
 overflow: hidden;
}
#video-background {
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: 50%;
 transform: translate(0, -50%);
 -webkit-transform: translate(0, -50%);
 -moz-transform: translate(0, -50%);
 -o-transform: translate(0, -50%);
 -ms-transform: translate(0, -50%);
 width: 100% !important;
 min-height: 100%;
 width: auto;
 height: auto;
 z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-video">
  <video autoplay="" loop="" id="video-background" muted="">
    <source src="http://duetdress.com/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</div>
```